# Notation and a problem with Aleatory variables (Advanced Probability)

Tags: probability

I am studying advanced probability and I have a question with notation.
One exercise says:
Let $(\Omega,B)$, show that $A \in B$ iff $1_A \in B$. But, $1_A$ is a function, what the book means with $1_A \in B$? Means that $1_A$ is a mensurable function?

Another question is:
Suppose $F(x) = P[X \le x]$ is continuos at $x$. Then $F(x)$ is mensurable and $Y = F(X)$ has uniform distribution, i.e.
$$P[Y \le y] = y, ~ y \in [0,1].$$

Comment: If $A\in B$ then $1_A$ is a measurable function with respect to $B$. This may be denoted by $1_A \in B$. Yes, since the cdf of $X=F^{-1}(U)$ is $F$. Then $F(X)=F(F^{-1}(U))=U$ where $U$ is uniform over $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zoli answered above $1_A \in \mathcal{B}$ means that $1_A$ is a $\mathcal{B}$- measurable function.

I would like to address your second question:

If $F(x)$ is continuous, then it is clear that $F$ is measurable, but let's look at Y = F(X):  for $a > 0$, the set $\{x: F(x)<a\} = (-\infty, Y(a)) $
where $Y(a) = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} F(x) \geq a$. Since F has no discontinuities we see that $F (Y(a)) = a$. Now
$$P(Y < a) = P(F(X)< a) = P(x< Y(a)) = F(Y(a)) = a $$

This is essentially the same idea of @zoli. I only wanted to avoid using $F^{-1}$ since the function might not be invertible.

**remark:** take $a_n \downarrow a$ to obtain $P(Y\leq a) = \lim_nP(Y \leq a_n) = \lim_n a_n = a$ this can also be used to the case $a = 0$